# android widget SearchView OnQueryTextListener

Tags: java, android, eclipse, scala

I want to implement search method for android in android Scala eclipse plug in:

I have this method :

```
val queryListener = new OnQueryTextListener() {

override def onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean = {
  if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
    getActivity.getActionBar.setSubtitle("List")
    val grid_currentQuery = null
  } else {
    getActivity.getActionBar.setSubtitle("List - Searching for: " + newText)
    val grid_currentQuery = newText
  }
  getLoaderManager.restartLoader(0, null, this)

  false
}
```

in this line " getLoaderManager.restartLoader(0, null, this)" I have an error for "this", My error is:

```
 type mismatch; found : android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener required: 
  android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks[?]
```

Would you please help me in this implementation

Thanks in advance!

**Update 1 :**

I used it before but still an error

```
 getLoaderManager.restartLoader(0, null, BooksFragment.this)
```

My Error is :

```
 Multiple markers at this line
- type mismatch; found : com.android.BooksFragment required: 
 android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks[?]
- type mismatch; found : com.android.BooksFragment required:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "this" refers to something with a type OnQueryTextListener. It should be a reference of variable with LoaderCallbacks[?] type instead.
Try replacing this with a LoaderCallbacks variable.

Maybe getLoaderManager.restartLoader(0, null, yourLoaderClassVariable)

For example, if you follow [the official android document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html), try

```
getLoaderManager.restartLoader(0, null, CursorLoaderListFragment.this)
```

Update:

```
class CursorLoaderListFragment extends ListFragment with OnQueryTextListener with OnCloseListener with LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks[Cursor] {
...
    def onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean = {
    ...
        getLoaderManager.restartLoader(0, null, CursorLoaderListFragment.this)
    ...
    true
    }
}
```

In your case, it might look like this:

```
class BooksFragment extends ListFragment with OnQueryTextListener with OnCloseListener with LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks[Cursor]
```

Update 2:
For the second error, try add these three lines. You can implement them later.

```
def onLoadFinished(l: Loader[Cursor], c: Cursor): Unit = ??? 
def onLoaderReset(l: Loader[Cursor]): Unit = ??? 
def onQueryTextChange(s: String): Boolean = ???
```

Comment: Do your class have the loader trait? "with LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks[Cursor]"

Comment: Eg...class CursorLoaderListFragment extends ListFragment with OnQueryTextListener with OnCloseListener with LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks[Cursor] {

Comment: I have but when i added the OnCloseListener I have this error not found: type 
 OnCloseListener

Comment: sorry I forgot to import android.widget.SearchView.OnCloseListener

Comment: yes:  class BooksFragment needs to be abstract, since: it has 3 unimplemented members. /** As seen from class BooksFragment, the missing signatures are as follows. * 
 For convenience, these are usable as stub implementations. */ // Members declared in android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks

Comment: def onLoadFinished(x
 $1: android.support.v4.content.Loader[android.database.Cursor],x$2: android.database.Cursor): Unit = ??? def onLoaderReset(x$1: 
 android.support.v4.content.Loader[android.database.Cursor]): Unit = ??? // Members declared in android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener def 
 onQueryTextChange(x$1: String): Boolean = ???

Comment: Basically, you have to implement all methods of the traits. Please see my update. Just add that three lines.

Comment: Can you try add the three lines (methods)? You should have them in your class because your class has the OnQueryTextListener and LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks[Cursor] traits.

Comment: Hmm, you're using trait...you can roughly think of it as protocol in Objective C. (Though, they are actually different.)

Comment: thanks now I don't have any error in my class but after running I have crash

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36052/discussion-between-entryleveldev-and-elnaz-shahmehr)